# Modify nuspec or similar to include symbol files

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a frequent debugging routine that I was hoping might be somewhat automated.

We build internal library packages that then are distributed across the organization via nugget for other developers to consume. It is not uncommon though for those developers to want to debug into the nugget package libraries as part of their troubleshooting.

When a developer request or when building a PreRelease nugget I manually will add the symbol files for debugging.

Is there a way to modify the nuspec or similar to automatically stick the symbol files in for me?

Comment: How do you distribute the nuget packages? If you've got an internal nuget server, perhaps you need an internal symbol server as well? Normally when you upload to nuget.org, it will upload to symbolsource as well... I assume that functionality is available for privately hosted servers too.

Comment: Hey Jon, Internal nuget server. I will dig in with that administrator and thanks to your pointer likely get it operational. Thx

Comment: I've never done it myself, but hopefully http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step is useful...